# Can HDFS replicate to other clusters?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

HDFS is replicating to fact 3 in the same cluster. That is fine, but is there a way to set up HDFS so it can replicate also to different clusters/servers? Let say 1 replication in to the same cluster and the other one somewhere far away in another HDFS cluster.

If HDFS is not supporting this, are there any tools around Hadoop that allow us to do so? How do you guys replicate over other servers?

Answer (score 4):

Currently there are no mechanisms for what you're asking for. Cross-cluster replication has been implemented for HBase, but not for HDFS. There is a [plan to support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5442) cross datacenter replication in HDFS but it's not implemented yet.

You can use the [distcp](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/DistCp.html) mechanism to copy your data to another cluster on a regular interval. This will place 3 replicas on each cluster (which is typically what you want for cross dc/cluster replication anyway). Note however that since this has to be done periodically, it's not exactly a replacement for realtime replication. If you lose a cluster in between copies, whatever data was written to the "primary" cluster will be lost until the cluster has been restored.